# Sub sub sub section with alphabet

Tags: subsection

I would like to ask how to make Sub sub sub section with an alphabet
I did with the `\paragraph{}` but it appeared as no number as figgure below:

[image]

Comment: Hello! Could you please provide the code so that others do not have to start from scratch.

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

The `secnumdepth` counter controls which divisions get numbered. For examplw with `setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} means that` \subsection`is numbered but`\subsubsection`and below are not numbered, while`\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} means that only `\part` and `\chapter` will be numbered.

For `\paragraph` to be numbered use

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
```

An MWE from you would have been very helpful as I could have used it to better give you an answer. (GOM)